# Does an abelian group must have a degree one faithful representation?

Tags: representation-theory

I know that if a finite group $G$ has degree one faithful representation over a field $F$, then it must be abelian. But is the converse true?

I know that there is trivial representation but it is not faithful. Any help on this is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: No: If $\phi : \Bbb Z / 3 \Bbb Z \to GL(1, F)$ is faithful, it maps any generator to a nontrivial cube root of unity, but some fields $F$ (e.g., $\Bbb Q$) do not contain any such roots.

Comment: No. The smallest counterexample is the Klein four group. The problem is that in a degree one representation there can be only a single matrix of order two. So if the group has more than one element of order two, the rep is not faithful. More generally, the set of groups of faithful 1-dimensional representations consists of exactly the cyclic groups. A finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of any field is cyclic.

Comment: "Smallest" in the sense that the choice of the field won't help unlike in Travis' example.

Comment: Dear blabla, can you give a reference of your first statement?

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is cyclic then the question of whether or not there exists a 1D faithful rep amounts to if the field contains enough roots of unity - specifically, if it has a $|G|$th root of unity.

If $G$ is not cyclic then it's impossible. The fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups says $G$ is a direct sum of cyclic groups, and by Chinese Remainder Theorem we can say $G$ is not cyclic iff there are a pair of cyclic summands (with respect to some choice of direct sum decomposition) that share a factor. Thus, $G$ has more than $\phi(d)$ elements of order $d$ for some number $d$, but there can be at most $\phi(d)$ such elements in the group of units of a field (good exercise), so there can be no faithful 1D rep of $G$ over any field.